# Need to pass pair as separate components to Json.obj

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm using Scala Play to process some JSON.  I tried this:

```
val pair = ("foo", "bar")
val json = Json.obj(pair)
```

This gives me

```
type mismatch;  found   : (String, String)  required: (String, play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper)
```

Okay, fair enough.  But if I do this instead:

```
val json = Json.obj(pair._1 -> pair._2)
```

Everything is fine.  But I thought `x -> y` was just syntactic sugar for `(x, y)`.  It looks as if the latter expression is just constructing a new pair that's identical to the original and passing it to `Json.obj`, but something is clearly different between the two cases.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The method `obj` takes tuples of type `(String, JsValue)*`. When you passed a tuple of `(String, String)`, the compiler complained of type mismatch. `(String, String)` is not same as `(String, JsValue)`

Now, from [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson)

```
Most values don’t need to be explicitly wrapped by JsValue classes,
the factory methods use implicit conversion
The Play JSON API provides implicit Writes for most basic types, 
such as Int, Double, String, and Boolean
```

When you passed `String -> String`, compiler has two options to implicitly convert `String -> String` to a tuple `(String, String)` or from `String -> String` to `String -> JsValue` to a tuple `(String, JsValue)`. The second option matches the type required for the `obj` method and compiler follows that way to get a error free code.